# While scaling up, how to make user uploaded files available accross multiple servers?

Tags: webserver, synchronization

I have a website in which users would upload various and later access them. 
The files are stored in a specific path in the server at this point. Now if I need to have multiple servers for the website, what is the best way to make the user uploaded files accessible across multiple servers. Amazon s3 is one option that has crossed my mind. What other options do I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can try using a CDN (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network).

Also, you can make it in house, by having specialized servers setup for static content. You will need maybe a lookup server, to know for each file on what server can be found. It will also contain the logic to determine what is the best server to use to save the file. This is more complicated, as you will have to make the load balancing and take care of geographic location of users.